# abobe air 3.8 NativeProcess.isSupported issue @ startup windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

(first-post)
i am having a problem with NativeProcess.isSupported.

its a simple app make in abobe flash publish in air 3.8 .exe. everything works great :)

- < supportedProfiles> desktop extendedDesktop tv extendedTV < /supportedProfilessetup.>
- NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true //after install, app start auto with win
- NativeProcess.isSupported
- var file: File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("PC_shutdown.exe") //after timer the pc shutdown

install the setup.exe file run in windows 8, thats work 100% of the time. (manual start)

as in code the app start with windows login (its work) but NativeProcess.isSupported is then false so shutdown.exe will not executed. but when i manual start the app NativeProcess.isSupported is true and .exe is executed.

first run is false > close app > restart then it's true??? i have no idea/logic.

thx

Answer (score 0):

NativeProcess support only works when you package your AIR application as a bundle (i.e. you create a self contained application with a copy of Adobe Air). This is done by specifying the "-target bundle" flag OR "-target native" flag when running adt.

[More info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html) on adt bundle/native installer flags